# php:get only date from timestamp SQL

Tags: php, date

Currently I have a datetime like this:

```
2012-07-24 11:52:01
```

Now i want to show only date like `2012-07-24`.

Can anyone give any php function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go ahead and use PHP's DateTime class. I was reluctant to move away from functions to classes, but it's really not that hard. Just pass the date string into the class object and then use the format method to output the date string in the way you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-07-24 11:52:01');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 8):

just follow the following procedure

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2012-07-24 11:52:01"));
```

in above code strtotime() returns value of date in seconds and "Y-m-d" transfers it in Y-M-D format of date as date() method is used.

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = "2012-07-24 11:52:01";
$pieces = explode(" ", $date);
echo $pieces[0];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check php manual for more reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Little research please

$today = date("Y-m-d ");